# Getting list of button.text() from a body

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i looked for hours but i only be able to get a single string with all text in one.

What i want is to get an array with every text of buttons.

here's my html :

```
<table class="table text-center table-borderless">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="table-danger t" scope="col">Paramètres disponibles</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody class="bodyDroite">
                <tr>
                    <td id=annees>
                        <button class="buttonParam" onclick="changeTable(this)">annees</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
               
                <tr>
                    <td id=producteurs>
                        <button class="buttonParam" onclick="changeTable(this)">producteurs</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
               
                 <tr>
                    <td id=depots>
                        <button class="buttonParam" onclick="changeTable(this)">depots</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                <tr>
                    <td id=commandes>
                        <button class="buttonParam" onclick="changeTable(this)">commandes</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
                 <tr>
                    <td id=clients>
                        <button class="buttonParam" onclick="changeTable(this)">clients</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

i want to make an array with all the buttons.text()

i tried that

```
let liste = [];
        $('.bodyDroite').each(function () {
            liste.push($(this).find('button').text());
        })
```

but all i get is a string with all texts in one line.
thanks for the help !

Comment: yeah my bad in fact it's 2 tables where i move the <tr>s from bodyGauche to bodyDroite, then i want to get all the values of the ones added on the right table to know what parameters are picked, i copied the wrong table, i'm correcting the code. thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You applied the each loop on one element `.bodyDroite` or `.bodyGauche` (!)... What you need to do is find all buttons first and run the each loop on on it.

```js
let liste = [];
$('.bodyGauche').find('button').each(function() {
  liste.push($(this).text());
})
console.log(liste)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table text-center table-borderless">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="table-danger t" scope="col">Paramètres disponibles</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody class="bodyGauche">
    <tr>
      <td id=annees>
        <button class="buttonParam" onclick="changeTable(this)">annees</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td id=producteurs>
        <button class="buttonParam" onclick="changeTable(this)">producteurs</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td id=depots>
        <button class="buttonParam" onclick="changeTable(this)">depots</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td id=commandes>
        <button class="buttonParam" onclick="changeTable(this)">commandes</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td id=clients>
        <button class="buttonParam" onclick="changeTable(this)">clients</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! i'm beginning in the Javascript/Jquery area, but it starting to become clear :)
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) to make this much easier

```js
const liste = $(".bodyDroite button").map(function() {
  return $(this).text()
}).get()
```

You can also do this just as simply without jQuery at all

```js
const liste = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".bodyDroite button"),
  btn => btn.textContent)
```

Comment: thank you for your response, i'll study the .map() function, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

There is no `bodyDroite` class.
You should iterate over `.find(button)`

```
$('button').each(function () {
   console.log($(this).text());
})
```

Comment: OP updated their question to include the correct class name on `<tbody>`